# Assign string value for decimal value

Tags: c#, type-conversion, variable-assignment

```
_item = new OutTYonetimOzet();

_item.Banka = Convert.ToDecimal(" "); 

liste.Add(_item);
```

There is a list called `liste`. In List item `Banka` named element is decimal value. I want to show the empty string when I show it on the screen. But this code is getting an error that can not be cast. What is the problem.

Error message is:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Well want `decimal` value do you expect that to parse to? It sounds like you probably want to use `Nullable<decimal>`

Comment: Are you sure you can cast emptry string to decimal ? :o

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as a "blank decimal". `decimal` cannot have a value that is "blank" - it always has a numeric value. `Convert.ToDecimal(" ")` is nonsensical - there is nothing it can return that makes sense.

You could try using a `Nullable<decimal>` (aka `decimal?`) perhaps; i.e.

```
public decimal? Banka {get;set;}
```

and

```
_item.Banka = null;
```

Comment: _item.Banka = Nullable<decimal>; is which is not valid in given comment.

Comment: You will need to change the implementation of `_item` so `Banka` is of type `Nullable<decimal>`

Comment: @Marc Exactly... in case it isn't obvious enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `decimal.TryParse` instead of `Convert`. With this technique you can check if the string is valid.

```
        _item = new OutTYonetimOzet();

        decimal val = decimal.MinValue;

        if (decimal.TryParse(" ", out val))
        {
            _item.Banka = val;
        }
        else
        {
            //your default goes here
            _item.Banka = 0;
        }

        liste.Add(_item);
```

and as Mark suggested I would use `Nullable<decimal>` and use null as default value.

Comment: This would be a correct solution for some random input string, not for a hardcoded space. And it would still show a `0` where a "blank" was wanted.

Comment: that's why I added the comment "your default goes here" and that nullable should be used. BTW I assumed that OP posted a [MCVE] so the blank is not hardcoded...

Comment: _item.Banka = Nullable<decimal>;   is which is not valid in given comment. @Mat